# How to get tkinter.Entry to save comment when used with matplotlib 'key_press_event'?

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter

I've written a pretty complex plotting utility for user interaction. interaction is handled via `fig.canvas.mpl_connect('key_press_event', on_key)` and `fig.canvas.mpl_connect('pick_event', onpick)`

What i'd like is using the `key_press_event` when the user presses 'c' it will raise a `tkinter.Entry` window for the user to add a comment.

This comment is then extracted and stored, and the user moved on.

The `tkinter.Entry` implementation works perfectly fine in isolation.

So i have `tkComment.py` here:

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import Entry, StringVar

class tkComment(object):

    def __init__(self):
        root = self.root = tkinter.Tk()
        tkinter.Button(root,text="save comment",command=root.destroy).pack(anchor=tkinter.S,side=tkinter.BOTTOM)

        entryVar = self.entryVar = tkinter.StringVar()
        entry = self.entry = Entry(master=root, width=60, textvariable=self.entryVar)
        entry.pack(side=tkinter.TOP)
```

I'm using IPython for easy testing (but the problem persists outside of Ipython). I import this `tkComment` and have a few functions for testing

```
from __future__ import print_function

import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("TkAgg") #necessary for use with tkinter
from tkComment import tkComment

def runtkc():
    global tkC
    tkC = tkComment()
    tkC.root.mainloop()

def print_comment():
    global tkC
    print('comment for this source:', tkC.entryVar.get())

from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

def on_key(event):
    global tkC

    if event.key == 'c':
        runtkc()

    if event.key == 'C':
        print_comment()

def test_plot():
    fig,ax = plt.subplots(1)
    ax.plot(range(10))
    keyID = fig.canvas.mpl_connect('key_press_event', on_key)
    plt.show()
```

Now, the problem:

if I just call `runtkc()` then `print_comment()` everything works perfectly fine.

if I call these functions through a key-press in `test_plot()` the stored string is empty. Even when printed from within `tkComment.tkComment` !!

How do I get these fellas to cooperate?

Comment: If you downvoted me, please provide a comment as to how I can improve this question. I have spent several days (and nights) working on this and have exhausted my coding abilities. There is no duplicate question on SO or any other site, this seems to be a unique issue as far as I can tell.  I also spent a bit of time writing as clean of a minimum working example as I could to facilitate easy debugging for SO.

Comment: This example is not minimal. Not only have you included aesthetically pleasing configuration options you haven't trimmed your code down to only the affected area. You need to give us the logic which seems to be broken, some sort of input and some sort of output. **None** of the rest of the program is necessary provided it can run.

Comment: @EthanField I honestly think that this example is minimal. Any extra code is there to help us understand the issue and show that the class itself is working as expected. This should not be discouraged, as everyone who would want to help would otherwise need to write those test cases himself. That being said, it would of course make sense to try to find a minimal *working* example in the sense of finding a case where the variable *can*  be stored and read from a class. This can be part of the debugging which would eventually allow to see the differences between working and non-working.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest It would be better if OP were to provide a program which passes a prewritten input or generates an input through the algorithm which has a problem and displays an output. It doesn't need anything more than that.

Comment: @EthanField so if you already know that the problem is not caused by the text being read from a text input, that would be an interesting piece of information you may share with the questioner, who is for sure interested in any step towards a solution.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I don't know that, I never claimed to know that.

Comment: @EthanField I assumed so, but if you claim that the example can be simplified by leaving the text input out, it is the same as saying that it would not be the source of the problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155436/discussion-between-ethan-field-and-importanceofbeingernest).

Comment: Thanks for the input @EthanField, I've pruned the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is that matplotlib is creating its own instance of tkinter. So when you call `root = self.root = tkinter.Tk()` in `tkComment.__init__` you have two instances of tkinter, and matplotlib is talking to a different one.

if you instead call
`root = self.root = tkinter.Toplevel()`

this problem is avoided.